# HugeInteger using 40-element array of digits

Tags: java, arrays

I am working a challenge and I keep getting errors when I run the compiler. I'm newer to java and I can't see what is wrong. I am not looking for an answer, but more of clarification on where I need to be looking.

I am to create a class HugeInteger which uses a 40-element array of digits to
store integers as large as 40 digits each. Provide methods parse, toString, add and subtract. Method
parse should receive a String, extract each digit using method charAt and place the integer
equivalent of each digit into the integer array. For comparing HugeInteger objects, provide the following
methods: isEqualTo, isNotEqualTo, isGreaterThan, isLessThan, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo
and isLessThanOrEqualTo. Each of these is a predicate method that returns true if the relationship
holds between the two HugeInteger objects and returns false if the relationship does not hold. Provide
a predicate method isZero.

```
public class HugeInteger{
  private int[] intArray;
  private int numDigits;  // stores the number of digits in intArray
  //static String ss;

  public HugeInteger(String s){
    intArray = new int[40];
    numDigits = 0;
    parse(s);// call parse(s)
  }

  public HugeInteger( ){
    intArray = new int[40];
    numDigits = 0;
    
  }
  
  public void parse(String s){
     // Add each digit to the arrays
     // update numDigits
     for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
         intArray[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
         System.out.print(intArray[i] + "");
         numDigits++;
         System.out.print(intArray[i] + "" + numDigits);
      }
  }

  public static HugeInteger add(HugeInteger hugeInt1, HugeInteger hugeInt2){
     // Create hugeInt3
     // Loop 
     //    Add digits from hugeInt1 and hugeInt2, 
     //    Store in corresponding hugeInt3
     // End
     //
     // return hugeInt3  
      HugeInteger hugeInt3 = new HugeInteger();
      for (int i = 0; i < hugeInt3.intArray.length; i++){
      hugeInt3.intArray[i] = hugeInt1.intArray[i] + hugeInt2.intArray[i];
  }
      String data = hugeInt3.intArray.toString();
      for (int j = 0; j < data.length(); j++)
          System.out.println(hugeInt3.intArray[j]);
      return hugeInt3;
  }

  public static HugeInteger subtract(HugeInteger hugeInt1, HugeInteger hugeInt2){
     // Create hugeInt3
     // Loop 
     //    Subtract hugeInt2 digit from  hugeInt1, 
     //    Store in corresponding hugeInt3
     // End
     //
     // return hugeInt3  
      HugeInteger hugeInt4 = new HugeInteger();
      for (int i = 0; i < hugeInt1.intArray.length; i++){
          if (hugeInt1.intArray[i] > hugeInt2.intArray[i])
              hugeInt4.intArray[i] = hugeInt1.intArray[i] - hugeInt2.intArray[i];
          else
              hugeInt4.intArray[i] = hugeInt2.intArray[i] - hugeInt1.intArray[i];
      }
      
      String data = hugeInt4.intArray.toString();
      for (int j = 0; j < data.length(); j++)
          System.out.println(hugeInt4.intArray[j]);
      return hugeInt4;

  }

  public static boolean isEqualTo(HugeInteger hugeInt1, HugeInteger hugeInt2){
    // return true if the value represented by 
    // elements of hugeInt1.intArray is equal to
    // value represented by elements of hughInt2.intArray
      for (int i = 0; i < hugeInt2.intArray.length; i++)
          System.out.println(hugeInt2.intArray[i]);
      int count = 0;
      
      for (int i = 0; i < hugeInt2.numDigits; i++){
          int a1= hugeInt1.intArray[i];
          int a2 = hugeInt2.intArray[i];
          System.out.println(a1 + " " + a2);
          if (a1 != a2){
              System.out.println(hugeInt2.intArray[i]);
          count++;
      }
      }
      
      System.out.println("count" + count);
      return count <= 0;
  }

  public static boolean isNotEqualTo(HugeInteger hugeInt1, HugeInteger hugeInt2){
    // return true if the value represented by 
    // elements of hugeInt1.intArray is not equal to
    // value represented by elements of hughInt2.intArray
      
      for (int i = 0; i < hugeInt2.intArray.length; i++)
          System.out.println(hugeInt2.intArray[i]);
      int count = 0;
      
      for (int i = 0; i < hugeInt2.numDigits; i++){
      int a1 = hugeInt1.intArray[i];
      int a2 = hugeInt2.intArray[i];
      System.out.println(a1 + " " + a2);
      if (a1 != a2){
          System.out.println(hugeInt2.intArray[i]);
          count++;
      }
  }
      System.out.println("count" + count);
      return count > 0;
  }

  public static boolean isGreaterThan(HugeInteger hugeInt1, HugeInteger hugeInt2){
    // return true if the value represented by 
    // elements of hugeInt1.intArray is greater than 
    // value represented by elements of hughInt2.intArray
      int sum1 = 0;
      int sum2 = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < hugeInt1.intArray.length; i++){
          sum1 += hugeInt1.intArray[i];
          sum2 += hugeInt1.intArray[i];
      }
      
      return sum1 > sum2;
      
  }

  public static boolean isLessThan(HugeInteger hugeInt1, HugeInteger hugeInt2){
    // return true if the value represented by 
    // elements of hugeInt1.intArray is less than
    // value represented by elements of hughInt2.intArray
      
      int sum1 = 0;
      int sum2 = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < hugeInt1.intArray.length; i++){
          sum1 += hugeInt1.intArray[i];
          sum2 += hugeInt1.intArray[i];
      }
      return sum1 >= sum2;
  }

  public static boolean isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(HugeInteger hugeInt1, HugeInteger hugeInt2){
    // return true if the value represented by 
    // elements of hugeInt1.intArray is greater than or equal to
    // value represented by elements of hughInt2.intArray
      int sum1 = 0;
      int sum2 = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < hugeInt1.intArray.length; i++){
          sum1 += hugeInt1.intArray[i];
          sum2 += hugeInt1.intArray[i];
      }
      return sum1 >= sum2;
  }

  public static boolean isZero(HugeInteger hugeInt1 ){
    // return true if the value represented by 
    // elements of hugeInt1.intArray is 0 
      int count = 0;
              for (int i = 0; i < hugeInt1.intArray.length; i++){
                  if (hugeInt1.intArray[i]==0)
                      count++;
              }
              
      return count > 0;
  }

  public String toString( ){
     // return string representation of this object
     return toString();
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args){
      HugeInteger h = new HugeInteger("abc");
      HugeInteger h2 = new HugeInteger("xyz");
      HugeInteger h3 = new HugeInteger();
      HugeInteger hall = new h3.add(h,h2);
      boolean b = HugeInteger.isNotEqualTo(h,h2);
      System.out.println(b);
      boolean iszero = HugeInteger.isZero(h);
      System.out.println(iszero);
      System.out.println(HugeInteger.isEqualTo(h,h2));
      System.out.println(HugeInteger.isNotEqualTo(h,h2));
      System.out.println(HugeInteger.isGreaterThan(h,h2));
      System.out.println(HugeInteger.isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(h,h2));
      System.out.println(HugeInteger.isLessThan(h,h2));
      
     }      
}
```

I think the issue comes up when I test it, more specifically here: HugeInteger hall = new h3.add(h,h2);

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal` as part of JDK. Do you have a specific reason why you need to use your own implementation (homework, learning...)?

Comment: It's for homework and the template was provided, so I am tied to HugeInteger unfortunately and that has me completely stumped.

Comment: 'the issue' - what issue? A compiler error? Paste it. A runtime error? Paste the stack trace. An answer you did not expect? Paste that answer and paste what you wanted to see.

Comment: `new h3.add` isn't legal java and I'm having a hard time understanding what you think that might have done. `new HugeInteger()` is. But `add` is a static method. You presumably want `HugeInteger h3 = HugeInteger.add(h, h2);` instead of the two lines (`HugeInteger h3 = ...` and `HugeINteger hall = ...`. That is probably not the only error in this code. Write less, test more.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the task you're looking to accomplish with `hall = new h3.add(h,h2)`?  Should `hall` be the sum of `h` and `h2`?

Comment: There is no need to define `HugeInteger h3 = new HugeInteger()` at all.  `HugeInteger.add()` is a static method. So, it can be called directly without an object.   And yes, `HugeInteger hall = new h3.add(h,h2)` is totally invalid - source of compilation error. ```HugeInteger hall = HugeInteger.add(h, h2);``` is enough. Deleting those 2 lines and replacing those with just this one line resolves the compilation error.

Comment: @Reilas yes, that is the intent of the hall, but I get an error saying that it is never read.

Comment: @julio11, you don't need the `new` keyword.  That's only for instantiation.  In this case, the instantiation was within the `add` method, at `hugeInt3 = new HugeInteger()`.  [Creating Objects (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).